# In specific search terms in Google, if you use `-site:` and there's a result with "Must Include", it will include the dashes

Tags: google-search

I have the search query `harvard wifi dns -site:pinterest.com -site:githubmemory.com -site:numerade.com -site:coursehero.com -site:chegg.com -site:scribd.com`. However, in one of the results, I get [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UySiS.png). How would I get rid of this? `-inurl:` does not have this problem, though using it may exclude results I may want.